# How make NSTextView not selectable, but allow to select links

Tags: swift, objective-c, appkit, nstextview

So I have NSTextView with attributed string which contain links from html markup. I want to make links clickable, but other text don't.

Delegate method which apple propose
textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:
(in topic https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449297-selectable)
is not working as I want, I can only remove selection after it already has been selected

And property isSelectable block any mouse events, so link are not clickable either

Comment: Use the view-based table view and select None for the Highlight property.

Comment: Google found [HyperlinkTextView](https://gist.github.com/mminer/597c1b2c40adcf3c319f7feeade62ed4).